# vagrant package creates a copy of the original box with no changes I have made

Tags: windows, vagrant

This may be a noob question, but after making some changes to an image with `vagrant up` and then installing something, I then call `vagrant package --box [name] --output [new.box]`.

After I create a new vagrant init from `new.box`, it doesn't have the new things I installed on the box that I packaged.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the box name you used when packaging? Did you use the base box name or the instance you see when `VBoxManage list runningvms` when it is up and running (BTW: you can see the same in VirtualBox GUI)? Make sure you use the correct name, e.g. `base_default_1234567890`.

I guess most likely you packaged the

Answer (score 1):

The reason could be that you used the same box name.

As you described, you've done something like this:

1. Created a `Vagrantfile`:

   ```
   Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
     config.vm.box = 'base'
     config.vm.box_url = 'http://the-url-of-box-you-used-as-base.com/precise.box'
   end
   ```
2. `vagrant up`
3. `vagrant ssh` => there you've made some changes
4. `vagrant package --box [name] --output [new.box]`
5. Edit the original `Vagrant` file (or create a new one) to load your new box:

   ```
   Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
     config.vm.box = 'base'
     config.vm.box_url = 'my-new.box'
   end
   ```

And here I'm assuming you kept the `config.vm.box` the same, which means Vagrant didn't use your box, but the original previous box as there's already downloaded box with that name in your `~/.vagrant.d/boxes`.

There might be two solutions:

1. Change the name in `Vagrantfile` (if you have actually used different name when generating custom box)
2. Delete cached box with that name = remove `~/.vagrant.d/boxes/[name]`